# Docker-Compose cannot find config env file

Tags: postgresql, docker, go

I've created image from my Go project that has config env file. Here's my script for docker file

```
FROM alpine AS base
RUN apk add --no-cache curl wget

FROM golang:1.15 AS go-builder
WORKDIR /go/app
COPY . /go/app
RUN GO111MODULE=on  CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o /go/app/main ./main.go

FROM base
COPY --from=go-builder /go/app/main /main
CMD ["/main"]
```

Also i create docker-compose file to connect with postgresql like this:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres
    ports:
    - 5432:5432
    networks:
      - go_network
  app-golang:
    container_name: app1
    image: app-go:1.0
    ports:
    - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    networks:
      - go_network
    env_file:
      - /env/config

networks:
    go_network:
      name: go_network
```

My env file is in config file format, and as seen above, i store it on `/env/config`. The problem is when i do `docker-compose up -d` the log is said cannot find /env/config like this `ERROR: Couldn't find env file: /env/config` Is it has different function to read from config format file?

EDIT 1:
my env file is in config format as shown below, and I'm using "github.com/kenshaw/envcfg" package to read config file using envcfg:
[image: config]

Comment: Is the `env/config` file in your project directory? If so, you may need to remove the leading `/` (I've never used the `env_file` option so I'm just guessing)

Comment: the env path is like ```project/env/config``` I already try using just config and move my config to same directory with ```docker-compose.yml``` still not working

Comment: Looking at https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#using-the---env-file--option, all the example name the file starting with `.env` which is the standard convention. Maybe try moving the file to the same directory as `docker-compose.yml` and rename the file to `.env`. Then use just `- .env` for `env_file` (without a leading `/`)

Comment: I've move my config file to same directory as ```docker-compose``` but still doesn't work.. let me edit my question to add config file

Comment: I understand you tried moving it to the same directory. But did you try removing the `/` on the front of the path when you specify `env_file`? By using `/env/config` you are using an absolute path that tells it to look for `/env/config` on your local machine (which doesn't exist). You need to try either `env/config` or `./env/config` to tell it to look for that path in the same directory as `docker-compose.yml` is in.

Comment: If you did try it without the leading `/` then sorry, I'm not sure what the problem is :(

Comment: i did :( and still

Comment: Where are you launching the `docker-compose` command from ? The path here should be a path from your host, not your container. See [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/)